# How to make ImageTransformation produce an anamorphic version of image

Tags: image-processing, wolfram-mathematica

I'm experimenting with the ImageTransformation function to try to make anamorphic versions of images, but with limited progress so far. I'm aiming for the results you get using the image reflected in a cylindrical mirror, where the image curves around the central mirror for about 270 degrees. The [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anamorphosis) has a couple of neat examples (and I borrowed Holbein's skull from them too).

```
i = Import["../Desktop/Holbein_Skull.jpg"];
```

[image: wikipedia holbein skull]

```
i = ImageResize[i, 120]
f[x_, y_] := {(2 (y - 0.3) Cos [1.5 x]), (2 (y - 0.3) Sin [1.5 x])};
ImageTransformation[i, f[#[[1]], #[[2]]] &, Padding -> White]
```

[image: wikipedia holbein skull]

But I can't persuade Mathematica to show me the entire image, or to bend it correctly. The anamorphic image should wrap right round the mirror placed "inside" the centre of the image, but it won't. I found suitable values for constants by putting it inside a manipulate (and turning the resolution down :). I'm using the formula:

```
x1 = a(y + b) cos(kx)
y1 = a(y + b) sin(kx)
```

Any help producing a better result would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In `ImageTransformation[f,img]`, the function `f` is such that a point `{x,y}` in the resulting image corresponds to `f[{x,y}]` in `img`. Since the resulting image is basically the polar transformation of `img`, `f` should be the inverse polar transformation, so you could do something like

```
anamorphic[img_, angle_: 270 Degree] :=
  Module[{dim = ImageDimensions[img], rInner = 1, rOuter},
    rOuter = rInner (1 + angle dim[[2]]/dim[[1]]);
    ImageTransformation[img,
      Function[{pt}, {ArcTan[-#2, #1] & @@ pt, Norm[pt]}],
      DataRange -> {{-angle/2, angle/2}, {rInner, rOuter}},
      PlotRange -> {{-rOuter, rOuter}, {-rOuter, rOuter}},
      Padding -> White
    ]
  ]
```

The resulting image looks something like

```
anamorphic[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}]]
```

[image: anamorphic plot]

Note that you can a similar result with `ParametricPlot` and `TextureCoordinateFunction`, e.g.

```
anamorphic2[img_Image, angle_: 270 Degree] := 
  Module[{rInner = 1,rOuter},
    rOuter = rInner (1 + angle #2/#1 & @@ ImageDimensions[img]);
    ParametricPlot[{r Sin[t], -r Cos[t]}, {t, -angle/2, angle/2}, 
      {r, rInner, rOuter}, 
      TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#3, #4} &),
      PlotStyle -> {Opacity[1], Texture[img]},
      Mesh -> None, Axes -> False,
      BoundaryStyle -> None,
      Frame -> False
    ]
  ]
anamorphic2[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}]]
```

**Edit**

In answer to Mr.Wizard's question, if you don't have access to `ImageTransformation` or `Texture` you could transform the image data by hand by doing something like

```
anamorph3[img_, angle_: 270 Degree, imgWidth_: 512] :=
 Module[{data, f, matrix, dim, rOuter, rInner = 1.},
  dim = ImageDimensions[img];
  rOuter = rInner (1 + angle #2/#1 & @@ dim);
  data = Table[
      ListInterpolation[#[[All, All, i]], 
        {{rOuter, rInner}, {-angle/2, angle/2}}], {i, 3}] &@ImageData[img];
  f[i_, j_] := If[Abs[j] <= angle/2 && rInner <= i <= rOuter, 
    Through[data[i, j]], {1., 1., 1.}];
  Image@Table[f[Sqrt[i^2 + j^2], ArcTan[i, -j]], 
   {i, -rOuter, rOuter, 2 rOuter/(imgWidth - 1)},
   {j, -rOuter, rOuter, 2 rOuter/(imgWidth - 1)}]]
```

Note that this assumes that `img` has three channels. If the image has fewer or more channels, you need to adapt the code.

Comment: How is this "(an) image reflected in a cylindrical mirror" as the OP describes?  I am not saying this is wrong, only that I don't understand it.

Comment: @Mr Wizard - You stick a cylindrical mirror in the centre and the reflection shows the image correctly, even though the distorted anamorphic image is (or would be, except to Mathematica-ers) unrecognisable.

Comment: @cormullion I see.  FWIW, the Lena (sometimes Lenna) image is used far beyond the Mathematica community.  Search for it some time... ;-)

Comment: Heike, is there an easy way to do this without `ImageTransformation`, which is absent from v7?

Comment: Oh, NOW you show up, right after belisarius goaded me into posting that tragedy in the other thread.  It's a conspiracy!  (Seriously, thanks for showing me a better way.)