# Inside-out image transform

Tags: image-processing, wolfram-mathematica

After exploring the very excellent answer from Heike to my [previous question about anamorphic transformations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8235517/how-to-make-imagetransformation-produce-an-anamorphic-version-of-image), I eventually wanted to see an image turned inside out completely.

The idea is that, instead of just stretching the image out with an anamorphic transform, like you're pulling the edges of the paper around, you can actually turn the paper 'inside out'. The inside 'pixels' will be pulled out to the edges (greatly distorted/stretched), while the outside pixels will be squashed inwards towards the centre (greatly shrunk).

I can't illustrate it, but another way of trying to describe it is in this picture:

[image: inside out image transform]

so, the more red the pixels are, the more they are transformed to the edges (and vice versa).

I tried FindGeometricTransform, but it didn't seem to lead anywhere.

[image: findgeometrictransform]

It's not been easy to google for this, and I've yet to find any clues in Mathematica that such a destructive transformation is possible. It's kind of a 2.5D re-projection.

What do you think? Is it possible?

*Edit*

So thanks to your great answers I can now illustrate my question properly:

Here's Leonardo's famous Anom Asil, the result of subjecting poor Lisa to the inside-out transform ():

[image: introverted mona lisa]

and here's the Prague Orloj:

[image: inside out clock]

Practical uses for this will be forthcoming, er, soon...

Thanks!

Comment: Belated +1 for a fun question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
f[x_, y_] := {x, y} (1/Norm@{x, y} - 1);
GraphicsGrid[{{ 
       p = Rasterize[Graphics[ {Black, Disk[{0, 0}, 5],
                                Red,   Disk[{0, 0}, 3],
                                Blue,  Disk[{0, 0}, 2]}]],
       ImageTransformation[p, f[#[[1]], #[[2]]] &, 
                           DataRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]}}, 
       Frame -> All]
```

[image]

**Edit**

Using Heike's `f`the function is bijective, and it's own inverse:

```
f[x_, y_] := {x, y} (1/Norm[{x, y}, Infinity] - 1);
g[x_]:=ImageTransformation[x, f[#[[1]], #[[2]]] &,DataRange ->{{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]

GraphicsGrid[{{i, g@i, g@g@i}}, Frame -> All]
```

[image]

**Edit**

Setting:

```
f[x_, y_, t_] := {x, y} ((1/Norm[{x, y}, Infinity] - 1 ) t + (1 - t));
```

[image]

Comment: belisarius, you seem to know your way around image processing.  Is there a reasonably easy way to do a transformation like that, with the smooth sampling, in version 7?  (btw, since I can't test this, I'll hold my +1 until it is confirmed to work, as that seems most honest)

Comment: @Mr. Thanks! I think in v7 I would go along the lines described in your answer (which I SHALL upvote if you produce some code :)

Comment: Okay belisarius, I put up code, and somewhere an image processing expert weeps in solitude.

Comment: If you want a one-to-one mapping you could use f[x_,y_]:={x, y} (1/Norm[{x, y},Infinity] - 1) for the transformation function

Comment: @Heike yep, that is right. Feel free to add another answer or edit mine!

Comment: @belisarius That works perfectly (see original question), thanks!

Comment: @belisarius Do you think you could add some math and explanation around your code? I'd like to get this moved to [dsp.se] and we'd like a little bit of explanation there :)

Comment: @yoda Sorry, I am _against_ moving SO content to specialized sites if it can be answered here. Niche sites usually just don't get enough visits to make it worth contributing there.

Comment: @belisarius I understand your view and unfortunately, a lot of people hold that view. In the end, if everyone thinks that it doesn't get enough visits, hence not worth visiting, then it will never get enough visits to make it worth contributing. It's a cycle.

Comment: @yoda Yes. But at least in my case is based on some belief and experience, and not only in prejudice. I strongly see CS as a whole, and not as a set of specialization bins. Perhaps reading Knuth when I was a child spoiled me :)

Comment: Apart from mma and a few other tags (and a few questions in other tags), [so] is mostly 'Halp! I haz no output!' The interesting image processing questions (and imho a lot of mma questions) are better off not being on SO as it's mostly underappreciated here. But to each his own :)

Comment: In any case, I'll keep bugging you ;) http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/712/measuring-length-of-dna-fibers-from-an-image-of-single-molecules

Comment: @yoda Ok done. But I think that question would receive much better attention here. Whatever.

Answer (score 3):

If the native transform functions do not accommodate this in a single pass, you could probably get what you want by converting the image to polar coordinates, then inverting the radius data.  Hopefully Heike will be along shortly to fix you up. ;-)

---

Against my better judgement, here is my rough and nasty code as an example.  Zero oversampling, poorly conceived, magic numbers, and generally useless.  But, belisarius asked for it, and here it is!

Starting with `img =` this image:

[image]

```
dat = ImageData[img];

atan2[0., 0.] := 0
atan2[a_, b_] := ArcTan[a, b]

coords = Array[
   Round@{# Cos[#2], # Sin[#2]} + 144 &[(144 - Norm[{#, #2}]), 
       atan2[#2, #]] &[N@#, N@#2] &, {289, 289}, -144];

Image@Apply[dat[[##]] &, coords, {2}]
```

Yields this pixellated atrocity:

[image]