# Transforming images using a function

Tags: image, wolfram-mathematica, image-scaling, wolframalpha, wolfram-language

How does one transform an image such that each pixel of the image is moved radially in/outwards by a certain amount that is determined by a user defined function? (In Wolfram Mathematica)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show what you have tried so far and how that failed

Comment: see `ImageTransformation`

Comment: also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8235517/how-to-make-imagetransformation-produce-an-anamorphic-version-of-image